# Prevent rendering when receiving GPS data in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am making an app to store GPS and mobile sensor data. I am trying to implement a TextInput, to store a little text aswell. The problem is that each time the sensors give a result the render method is called, so I can't update the text.

```
render(){
    this.fetchData(this.state.lat,this.state.lon,this.state.speed,this.state.accuracy, this.state.altitude, this.state.heading, this.state.x, this.state.y, this.state.z);
    this.fetchText(this.state.activity);

    return (
        <View>
          <Text>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Lat: </Text> {this.state.lat}
            <Text style={styles.title}>Lon: </Text> {this.state.lon}
            <Text style={styles.title}>Speed: </Text> {this.state.speed}
            <Text style={styles.title}>Accuracy: </Text> {this.state.accuracy}
            <Text style={styles.title}>Altitude: </Text> {this.state.altitude}
            <Text style={styles.title}>X: </Text> {this.state.x}
            <Text style={styles.title}>Y: </Text> {this.state.y}
            <Text style={styles.title}>Z: </Text> {this.state.z}
            <Text style={styles.title}>XG: </Text> {this.state.xg}
            <Text style={styles.title}>YG: </Text> {this.state.yg}
            <Text style={styles.title}>ZG: </Text> {this.state.zg}
            <Text style={styles.title}>Azimuth: </Text> {this.state.azimuth}
            <Text style={styles.title}>Pitch: </Text> {this.state.pitch}
            <Text style={styles.title}>Roll: </Text> {this.state.roll}
            <Text style={styles.title}>Steps: </Text> {this.state.steps}
          </Text>

        <TextInput
            style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
            onSubmitEditing={(activity) => this.setState({activity})}

            value={this.state.activity}
        />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect if the `TextInput` is focused with `isFocused()` and prevent the re-rendering by returning false on `shouldComponentUpdate()`. For example:

```
shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return !this.textInput.isFocused();
}
```

Of course, for this to work you need to set up `this.textInput` as a reference, so your `TextInput` should look something like this:

```
    <TextInput
        style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
        onSubmitEditing={(activity) => this.setState({activity})}
        ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }}
        value={this.state.activity}
    />
```